# best pace to add angular filters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

where is the best place to add a custom filter in angular?

I have set mine up on the controller as it makes sense to run logic at this level.

However someone has suggested that I create a filter, then call this via the view.

Intrigued to hear whats best practice and when you would use one or the other?

Thanks

Comment: Yes create it as a real filter using the provided api. This way you can use it in the view, and have it injected in the controller if need be.

Comment: Can either @OlivérKovács or Yoshi mention this as an answer so that this question is marked as "answered"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a really controller, or scope specific filter, and it just makes no sense anywhere else in the application, (or u just lazy) its ok to declare it in the controller. However if you like to reuse them - as I do - through the app or in other projects its good to have your filters in nice clean modules and just DI them.